# How to use the result of two find for a single xargs

Tags: linux, shell

I am on Ubuntu 14.04. Lets say there are unknown number of executables in  a folder.

```
ATest, BTest, CTest
```

I want to execute each executables with a custom command line argument that is related to it's name. For example,

```
valgrind --xml=yes --xml-file=ATest.log ./ATest 
valgrind --xml=yes --xml-file=BTest.log ./BTest 
valgrind --xml=yes --xml-file=CTest.log ./CTest
```

I can get the executables by

```
find . -executable -type f
```

I can get the custom command line argument by

```
find . -executable -type f -printf '%f\n'
```

I can do

```
find . -executable -type f | xargs -n 1 valgrind --xml=yes --xml-file=Test.log
```

but unfortunately the name of the log file is not customized. I've attempted to combine it as below but it didn't work

```
find . -executable -type f -printf '%f\n' && find . -executable -type f | xargs -n 2 valgrind --xml=yes --xml-file={}.log
```

What is the correct way to combine the result of two find for a single xargs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
find . -executable -type f -printf '%f\n' |
xargs -I {} valgrind --xml=yes --xml-file={}.log ./{}
```

Or this `xargs`:

```
find . -name '*Test' -executable -type f -print0 |
xargs -0 -I {} bash -c 'valgrind --xml=yes --xml-file="${1##*/}.log" "$1"' - {}
```

This will execute these 3 commands:

```
valgrind --xml=yes --xml-file=ATest.log ./ATest
valgrind --xml=yes --xml-file=BTest.log ./BTest
valgrind --xml=yes --xml-file=CTest.log ./CTest
```

Comment: How would you workaround if this needs to be executed in a higher directory, meaning when "find . -executable -type f" returns ./dir/ATest ./dir/BTest ./dir/CTest?

Comment: This works but the problem with just using find is it always return 0 (echo $?) even if the program fails. Would it be possible to use xargs?

Answer (score 0):

Use `xargs`'s -I switch:

```
edward@esmith-Dell-XPS-L502X:~/tmp$ ls
a  b  c
edward@esmith-Dell-XPS-L502X:~/tmp$ find . -type f -printf '%f\n' | xargs -IXXX echo XXX some more stuff -f XXX and more XXX
a some more stuff -f a and more a
c some more stuff -f c and more c
b some more stuff -f b and more b
```

Comment: How do you show something like ./a some more stuff a.log? In other words,  with the path stripped for the name of the log file.